# C++ templates, porting from vc2005 to 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-c++

On vs2005 all is a fine,but on vs2013 is not work.
I have code:

```
    template <
     typename _path_builder,
     typename _vertex_allocator
 >
 struct CBuilderAllocatorConstructor {
     template <template <typename _T> class _vertex>
     class CDataStorage :
         public _path_builder::CDataStorage<_vertex>,
         public _vertex_allocator::CDataStorage<typename _path_builder::CDataStorage<_vertex>::CGraphVertex>
     {
     public:
         typedef typename _path_builder::CDataStorage<_vertex> CDataStorageBase;
         typedef typename _vertex_allocator::CDataStorage<
             typename _path_builder::CDataStorage<
                 _vertex
             >::CGraphVertex
         > CDataStorageAllocator;
         typedef typename CDataStorageBase::CGraphVertex CGraphVertex;
         typedef typename CGraphVertex::_index_type _index_type;

     public:
         IC CDataStorage (const u32 vertex_count);
         virtual ~CDataStorage ();
         IC void init ();
     };
 };
```

But after porting on vs 2013 i'm got error: on line
`typedef typename _path_builder::CDataStorage<_vertex> CDataStorageBase;`

error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
what is happen?

**EDIT:
thanks all for reply,i'm all corrected**

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce the `template` keyword to let the parser know that `_path_builder::CDataStorage` is a template.

```
typedef typename _path_builder::template CDataStorage<_vertex> CDataStorageBase;
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for a nice explanation.

Comment: thanks for reply,i'm all corrected

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a tightening up of the compiler.
"<" is generally supposed to be "less than" unless preceeded by keyword template:

```
template <
typename _path_builder,
       typename _vertex_allocator
       >
       struct CBuilderAllocatorConstructor {
           template <template <typename _T> class _vertex>
               class CDataStorage :
                   public _path_builder::template CDataStorage<_vertex>,
                   public _vertex_allocator::template CDataStorage<_path_builder::template CDataStorage<_vertex>::CGraphVertex>
           {
               public:
                   typedef typename _path_builder::template CDataStorage<_vertex> CDataStorageBase;
                   typedef typename _vertex_allocator::template CDataStorage<
                       typename _path_builder::template CDataStorage<
                       _vertex
                       >::CGraphVertex
                       > CDataStorageAllocator;
                   typedef typename CDataStorageBase::CGraphVertex CGraphVertex;
                   typedef typename CGraphVertex::_index_type _index_type;

               public:
                   IC CDataStorage (const u32 vertex_count);
                   virtual ~CDataStorage ();
                   IC void init ();
           };
       };
```

Here is the msdn page on the specific error:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0afb82ta.aspx

Comment: "Tightening up" means "making more standards compliant".

Comment: thanks for reply,i'm all corrected